# Turning 2 textboxes into 1 variable for height and weight conversion in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a program that requires height and weight. The height has to be calculated as feet and inches, same with weight has to be stone and pounds. This requires 2 textboxes.

My question is how can i get the text boxes to turn into 1 variable?

Comment: You can get the value from both textboxes and concatenate it

Comment: You create a class (or a struct) `Parameters`  with two public members height and weight and declare the variable as type `Parameters`. Or do you mean something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function in Textbox Change or ButtonClick :

```
public long CalculateUnit(int flag , int number) //flag=Textbox Type
{

if(flag==1)
{
int totalInches = (number / 2.54); // This will take a floor function of Centimetres/2.54
int Feet = (totalInches - totalInches % 12) / 12; // This will make it divisible by 12
int inches = totalInches % 12; // This will give you the remainder after you divide by 12
result=inches; //or Feet
}
if(flag==2)
{
int Stone =number;
int Pounds = (Stone*14) ;
int Kilograms = (Pounds/2.2);
result=Kilograms; // or Pounds
}

return result;
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question OP asked

Comment: Please don't advocate the usage of some “magic” int flag. Use enums for that, or even better use separate methods for separate use cases.

Comment: Yes, enums is better. But my example was a shortcut function for above question @poke